# HTTPS API client for a webserver

Tags: python, webserver

I am trying to Design and implement a functional HTTPS API client for a web server.
The API client must comply with following requirements

**Authentication**

Requests must include an AUTH_TOKEN header. Client requests to authenticated endpoints (i.e. every endpoint except this one) without a valid token will return a 401 (Unauthorized) response.

**API End Points**

The web server hosts a single API endpoint, /v1/user. This endpoint is scoped with a user_id, e.g. /v1/user?user_id=INT. The following methods are supported: POST, PUT, GET, DELETE. Requests are scoped with a valid user_id, with the exception of POST, which returns the user_id in the request-response object.

Successful POST, PUT, and GET responses will be of the form

```
{'users': \[{
"user_id": INT,
"username": STRING,
"password": SHA1(USERNAME+PASSWORD)}\],
'errors': \[\]}
```

DELETE requests will be of the form

`{'users': \[\], 'errors': \[\]}`

**POST**

Create a user. The POST body must be of the form

`{"username": "STRING", "password": "STRING"}`

**PUT**

Update a user. The PUT body must be of the form

`{"username": "STRING", "password": "STRING"}`

**GET**

Return a user. If the user_id parameter is omitted, all users are returned.

**DELETE**

Delete a user.

Please help

**This code seems to work but I am unable to get all the requirements added in a graceful manner to this script so it's functional in any environment.**

```
import requests
import json

api_key = 'APIKEY'
domain = 'interview.canadacentral.cloudapp.azure.com'

# Set the API endpoint URL
endpoint = f'https://{domain}/v1/user'

# Set the request headers
headers = {
    'Authorization': f'Bearer {api_key}',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}

# Send GET request to retrieve users
response = requests.get(endpoint, headers=headers)

# Check if the request was successful (status code 200)
if response.status_code == 200:
    # Parse the response JSON
    users = response.json()

    # Print the retrieved users
    for user in users:
        print(f"User ID: {user['user_id']}")
else:
    # Print the error message if the request was not successful
    print(f"Error: {response.status_code}, {response.text}")
```

Comment: show in question what you get in `response.text`

Comment: did you tried to test server with `curl` or `postman`?

Comment: is this correct `API_KEY`? Maybe all problem is you have wrong key.

Comment: Yea the API Key is working now, but I am not able to incorporate all the conditions in the questions

Comment: describe all details in question (not in comments)

Comment: Done @furas Please comment if you can help

Comment: I would create functions like `def get_user(user_id=None)` (which will uses `requests.get(...)`), `def create_user(username, password)` (which will use `requests.post(...))`, etc. Most requests has send `?user_id=numer` and this needs `params={"user_id": user_id}` like `requests.get(..., params={"user_id": user_id})`

Comment: eventually at the end script I would create loop which asks for operation (get, create, delete) and parameters (id or username and password) - and it uses functions `get_user()`. `create_user()`, etc. This way user can test `client code`